# How do you Override onClick in an Android ImageButton derived class

Tags: android

I've seen this asked a thousand times in a thousand different ways, but still can't get it to work...

I created a class which I've derived from ImageButton. I want to define my "on-click" behavior in the class.

I know I can do something inside my Activity's onCreate like:

```
myButton b;
b = (myButton)findViewById(R.drawable.mybutton);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     ...etc...
```

but I want to define the code where it should be, **in the derived class**.

I first thought I could define it as:

```
 @Override public void onClick(View v) {
```

...but I get an error saying that I can't use "@Override" here because "onClick" isn't in the superclass. (When trying to remove "@Override", it just builds and runs, but never gets called). I've also tried:

```
 @Override public void onClickListener(View v) {
```

...and several variants of "implements onClickListener" and "implements OnClickListener" to no avail.

This should be fairly simple - any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          derivedClassFunction(v);
      }
  });

   public void derivedClassFunction(View v) {
          /* code...*/
   }
```

**Another way:**

```
public class DerivedClass extends ImageButton implements View.OnClickListener {
    /*code...*/
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    /*code...*/
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        /*code...*/
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh - so I think I get it - "OnClickListener" is an "interface", which contains a function "onClick". You have to call "setOnClickListener" and pass it the object, which supports that interface, and has that function implemented?

Answer (score 1):

This is because there actually is no method `onClick()` in views. The work is done in the `onUpKey()` in the `View` class.

However, if you want to listen to clicking events in the subclass, this could be done very easily. You can either create an inner class which implements `View.OnClickLister` and use it to listen to events or even simpler, implement the interface in your class and set it as a listener during construction. The latter will look like this:

```
class YourClass extends ImageButton implements View.OnClickListener {
    public YourClass() {
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Your code
    }
}
```

LAS_VEGAS has already posted how the first variant with the inner class may look like.